# Angular - uiRouter start at top when state change

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular (not Angularjs) with the uiRouter and wish to start at the top of the page when the route / state changes. Right now, as with most SPA's it switches state and the position is the same as it was before.

I couldn't find anything on how to fix this in the docs or anywhere else. Most answers are on Angular.js help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
ngOnInit()
{
  Subscription = this.router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .subscribe(event => {
            document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        });  
}
```

Comment: This is angular router... not uirouter